# Unity container - Get singleton in all threads

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container

What is the best pattern to get singleton instance of the class in every thread in a given application, using Unity container?

Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What do you mean by *get singleton instance of the class in every thread*? You mean every thread needs its own instance?

Comment: Every thread needs the same application global instance so if I change the instance in thread A thread B can see changes

Answer (score 3):

Just use a [`ContainerControlledLifetimeManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.containercontrolledlifetimemanager.aspx) then - it will give back the same instance everytime (as long as you use the same container)

### how to use

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType(typeof(IMyInterface), 
                       typeof(MyImplementation), 
                       "singletonReg", 
                        new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Comment: And how should I pass container to each thread? Is there any pattern for that?

Comment: you can pass it as a closure to your thread-method, as an static member to sometime, ... - how did you want to resolve instances from the container anyway if you did not think on this?

Answer (score 1):

Simply register your type with the `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager`.

The container is thread safe (derives `SynchronizedLifetimeManager`) and you can see the source code [here](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/27886941/).

Answer (score 1):

If you mean 'a singleton instance that is used by all threads' then just specify an appropriate lifetime manager during registration:

```
unityContainer.RegisterType<IMyService, MyService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager()); 

unityContainer.RegisterInstance<IMyService>(new MyService(), new ContainerControlledLifetineManager());
```

If you mean 'a unique singleton instance per thread' then maybe use the string taking signatures in Unity registration to provide the thread id (this would require per-thread registration and I suspect it is not what you meant):

```
unityContainer.RegisterType<IMyService, MyService>(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```